# Select field doesn't keep the value

Tags: html, flask

The select field doesn't keep it's value

I am developing a basic CRUD, with Flask and HTML

And a I added  a form to edit the informations of a row on a table. To make it better I developed in a way so that when the user clicks to edit a line, the information from that line would already go to the form, so that he does not need to fill in all the information again.

I made that by passing the parameter value to the flask form

`{{ form.nome.label() }} {{ form.nome(value=dados_membro.nome)}}`

And that worked for all fields but the select field, no matter what I type on the value parameter, nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the form data to the [form](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form) directly instead of to the individual form fields. The attributes `obj` and `data` accept the data either as an object or dictionary and the form fields are filled automatically.

Here is an example of the use of an object resulting from the database query.

```py
@app.route('/edit/<int:member_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(member_id):
    item = db.get_or_404(Member, member_id)
    form = EditForm(request.form, obj=item)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(item)
        db.session.commit()
        # ...
    return render_template('edit.html', **locals())
```